# PHP - FTP list files

Tags: php, ftp

I am new to the FTP feature of PHP. I have a directory within my FTP location called documents. I need to get the folders/files within another directory. So like this basically:

> root/documents/Ryan-Hart/ <-all-files/folders-here

So how can I show and link to these from PHP. I have tried this:

```
$name = "Ryan-Hart";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

print_r(ftp_nlist($conn_id,"/documents/$name"));
```

But that comes out in array. How can a echo out the name (plus extension) of file and link to them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that?

```
$arr= ftp_nlist($conn_id,"/documents/$name");

foreach ($arr as $value)
{
  echo '<a href="'.$value.'">'.basename($value).'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Basically I want the name of the file and extension within an anchor tag which links to the file. This helps for the anchor tag. :)

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you're looking for please?

Comment: Sure! <a href="/documents/Ryan-Hart/textFile.txt">textFile.txt</a>

Comment: That works with a slight adjustment to the href. However, is there anyway I can extract the filename and the extension to put between <a></a> because it's currently displaying the location. :)

Comment: Can you give me an exemple of output you have with this code?

Comment: (I've maid an adjustment in the second param of the `ftp_nlist()` call, it may be solve your problem)

Comment: Yep! <a href="/documents/Ryan-Hart/Text1.txt">/documents/Ryan-Hart/Text1.txt</a> that's with tweaks to your code.

Comment: Even with my last adjustment?

Comment: Nope that was the previous code. Here's the output now: <a href="documents/Ryan-Hart/./Text1.txt">/documents/Ryan-Hart/./Text1.txt</a> with some tweaks.

Comment: Just managed to do it by adding this in the 'foreach'.

$currDir = "/documents/$name/.";

$trimFile = ereg_replace("^$currDir", "", $value);
 
$trimFile = ereg_replace("^/", "", $trimFile);


Then: 

echo '<a href="'.$value.'">'.$trimFile.'</a><br>'; 
Thanks a lot for your help!! :D

Comment: is it not simple with the split()?

Comment: You're welcome, but what kind of server error? 500, PHP error? I'm quite surprised about this... What version of PHP do you use, and what is the OS?

Comment: I am running MAMP on my Mac. And PHP version 5.3.2. MAMP doesn't provide error details. Chrome just says 'Server error'. So not sure what's causing the problem :/

Comment: What about details in the developers tools (resources section)? http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/chrome/devtools/